# Why do I keep switching back to an old Node.js version with nvm-windows?

Tags: node.js, npm-install, nvm, nvm-windows

I am having issues with my node version and nvm. Using the command node -v shows I am using v20.1.0. I need to be using nvm 10.23.0. When I go to use 10.23.0, it prompts to allow this program to make changes, which I accept, and then it shows I have switched to node v10.23.0. However, when I use the command node -v again, it shows v20.1.0. This is my first time using node, npm, and nvm so I am unsure what I am supposed to be seeing. How can I correct my environment to have and use only node version 10.23.0?
Thank you.

I have tried uninstalling all versions of node and nvm and reinstalling 10.23.0 but the problem of having to allow changes and staying in 20.1.0 still occurs.

Comment: I'm having the same problem despite doing all as per the docs (& the answer underneath - did you ever find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i suggest you yo look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#installation--upgrades)

If you have correcly installed nvm you need to run your terminal as `administrator`

With command `nvm list available` you can check which versions are available in nvm.

With command `nvm install [version]` you are installing the version you want to use after the installation.

Once you installation has finished, type `nvm use [version]`.

At this point your job is done. Hope this can help you